# How to tell which row number is clicked in a href in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like the following:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td><a href="1" id='1' class'alert'>1</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td><a href="2" id='2' class'alert'>2</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td><a href="3" id='3' class'alert'>3</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When a user clicks on the `<a>`, how can I get the index of this row (tr element)?

For example, when I click on the first `<a>` it should pick it up and return `<td>1</td><td>1</td><td><a href="1" id='1' class'alert'>1</a></td>`.

Comment: `$('table a').click(function() { alert($(this).closest('tr').html());});`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get index by using **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**

```js
$('table a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click action
  alert($(this)
    .closest('tr') // get the tr
    .index() + 1 // get index based on siblings , add 1 since index start from 0
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="1" id='1' class 'alert'>1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="2" id='2' class 'alert'>2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a href="3" id='3' class 'alert'>3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you want to get number in `td` then use **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

```js
$('table a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click action
  alert($(this)
    .parent() // get parent td
    .prev('td') // get previous sibling
    .text() // get text
  );
  // or get first column by
  //  $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(0).text()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="1" id='1' class 'alert'>1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="2" id='2' class 'alert'>2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a href="3" id='3' class 'alert'>3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```